# div .height() changes after resize without telling it to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing a function in jQuery to Center an element vertically.
I have it run on load...
the code is as follows:

**JQuery**

```
var $window_height;
function Centerize(content) {
    content.css('margin-top', (($window_height - content.height())/2))
};

$(function(){
    $window_height = $(window).height();
    Centerize($('#welcome'));

    $(window).on('resize',function(){
        $window_height = $(window).height();
        Centerize($('#welcome'));
        });
})
```

The problem is that somehow on resize, my div height magically becomes different (60px shorter). Meaning, the first time it loads, it centers. On resize, The height is smaller, and therefore margin-top becomes larger, and the entire div is pushed down.

I've checked using console logs on $('#welcome').height().

The original value is 432px.  After resize, the value becomes 361px, and it remains that value even after I maximize Chrome.  Any ideas?

**SCSS**:

```
#welcome {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #DB9E36;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    text-align: center;

    div {
        margin: 50px auto;
        background-color: #FFE34E;
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        a {
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #FFFAD5;
            background-color: #BD4932;
            width: 100px;
            margin: 10px 10px;
            padding: 5px 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `#welcome` element?

Comment: It's a <div id="welcome"> with another div nested in it.  Directly in the body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do you absolutely need to use jQuery/JavaScript to achieve vertical center? It can easily be achieved via CSS by using the `top: 50%; margin-top:-100px` approach, where "100" would be half the height of your content. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lasha/dGcsB/

If you'd like to use jQuery, you can apply similar CSS dynamically, like what you tried to achieve with your code. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lasha/dGcsB/1/

As an added bonus, you can apply a similar technique to center an element within a parent container whose height dynamically changes: http://jsfiddle.net/lasha/dGcsB/2/

Enjoy the code samples. :)

**EDIT:** Oh, and to briefly explain what causes the height stuff to happen, is that in Chrome, for example, the 'ready' event is fired before the DOM has finished calculating the final dimensions of each element, so when you try to get the height or width of an element right on load, the browser may not have the most up to take info. This, as of this moment, is more of a Chrome thing, and Firefox doesn't usually have this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I've looked around for vertical centering techniques but it seems all of them have their caveats.  I've opened your first and second jsfiddles and switched between the tabs, and it seems like they're a little off from each other?

Comment: Alright, so I tried your examples out, but with your way, since position is absolute, margin: 0 auto wouldn't work.

Also, it doesn't seem vertically centered. check it out: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EAeJq)

Comment: To the #welcome div, if you update your margin property to be `margin: -100px 0 0 -250px;` and add `left: 50%`, you can horizontally center as well. Same technique as vertically centering.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that padding ADDS to the total height and width of your element, so when you do your negative margins for centering, you'll have to take those into consideration. You can stop padding from adding to the total dimensions of the element by applying `boxing-sizing: border-box` to the #welcome element. :)

Comment: @Lasha, I agree css solution is less jittery as long as you know the height of div in advance. Can you provide some recent links to the Chrome onload bug you are talking about? It sounds like a major issue and I'm sure it would be in a chrome bug report.

Comment: Here's a recent question I answered that involves this bug. =] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153460/div-height-changes-after-resize-without-telling-it-to/21154240#21154240

Comment: @Lasha, you need to stick with CSS ;)

Comment: @i-- I don't understand your suggestion. ;)

Comment: @Lasha, if you carefully read the original question by whyu and then my answer, that actually fixes the issue (inquirer stated so), you will discover that the window's onload event has actually resolves the issue. So my comment about you sticking with CSS meant that your claim about onload is baseless, ... or prove otherwise. Nothing against your answer in general, just disagree with the EDIT part.

Comment: @i-- FML. I actually meant to say `ready` in that edit. Will fix now. I do feel the CSS solution is the more suitable solution to avoid unnecessary interfacing with the DOM. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess this has to do with images being inside your #welcome div. Try replacing:

```
$(function(){
    $window_height = ...
```

with

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
   $window_height = ...
```

that should give images time to fully load.

Comment: Well that's interesting, the centering is consistent now, but it still doesn't include the padding in the div, which makes it appear pushed down towards the bottom instead of being dead center.

Comment: @whyu, try using `outerHeight()` instead of just `height()` for getting dimensions of your content.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I'll remember that outerHeight() includes the padding!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the height of the welcome element?  resizing the browser will probably resize that element as its height is not defined.

```
#welcome {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #DB9E36;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    height:200px;
    ...
```

at least see if that makes any difference in the behavior you're seeing

Comment: So I tried setting the height to a fixed 361px. The box looks pushed down and not centerized. Here's what the console logs yield both before and after:

    window height is: 600
    #welcome has a height of: 361
    margin-top should therefore be: 119.5

But something is wrong!  When I inspect the element, it shows 432px in the browser because it includes the padding (As it should). I've tried setting the height to 432px and it only elongates the div downwards without centering the div.